# How to make Fabric use a different role depending on which network it currently is?

Tags: python, ssh, fabric

I want to make a task use a different set of hosts (role) depending on which network I'm currently in. If I'm in the same network of my servers, I don't need to go through the gateway.

Here's a snippet from my fabfile.py:

```
env.use_ssh_config = True
env.roledefs = {
    'rack_machines': ['rack4', 'rack5', 'rack6', 'rack7'],
    'external_rack_machines': ['erack4', 'erack5', 'erack6', 'erack7']
    }

@roles('rack_machines')
def host_type():
    run('uname -s')
```

So, for my task `host_type()`, I'd like its role to be `rack_machines` if I'm in the same network as `rack4`, `rack5`, etc. Otherwise, I'd like its role to be `external_rack_machines`, therefore going through the gateway to access those same machines.

Maybe there's a way to do this with ssh config alone. Here's a snippet of my `ssh_config` file as well:

```
Host erack4
HostName company-gw.foo.bar.com
Port 2261
User my_user

Host rack4
HostName 10.43.21.61
Port 22
User my_user
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Role definitions are taken into account after module has been imported. So you can place some code in your `fabfile` which executes on import, detects network and set appropriate `roledefs`.

Second way to achieve a goal is to use "flag-task". This is a task which does nothing but set appropriate roledefs. I.e.:

```
hosts = {
    "rack": ["rack1", "rack2"],
    "external_rack": ["external_rack1", "external_rack2"]
}

env.roledefs = {"rack_machines": hosts["rack"]}

@task
def set_hosts(hostset="rack"):
    if hostset in hosts:
        env.roledefs["rack_machines"] = hosts[hostset]
    else:
        print "Invalid hostset"

@roles("rack_machines")
def business():
    pass
```

And invoke that way: `fab set_hosts:external_rack business`